# How to rename each jQuery cloned div's child elements id dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just cloned one div using jQuery clone, how can I rename each div elements id, and value after cloning, below is my code,

```js
 jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#act').click(function(){
        jQuery("#test").clone(true, true).insertAfter("div#test:last");
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
    <label class="label" for=""</label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="super_attribute" id="attribute" class="super-attribute-select">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty</span></label>
        <div class="control">
           <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title=""
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="act">
                <span>Add new item</span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: `jQuery("#test").clone(true, true)` returns `jQuery` object, you can apply `.attr` or `.prop` methods before `jQuery.insertAfter`

Comment: You want to update the ID of only the new elements? Or of all? And you probably want the ID's to be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function(){
  var len = 0;
     jQuery('#act').click(function(){
        jQuery("#test").clone(true, true).insertAfter("div#test:last");
       
       
    $('div#test:last').attr('id', 'test'+len);
       
       
       //set name for select box
    $('div#test'+len+' select').attr('name', 'super_attribute'+len);
       
       
       
       
len++;
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
    <label class="label" for=""</label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="super_attribute" id="attribute" class="super-attribute-select">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty</span></label>
        <div class="control">
           <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title=""
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="act">
                <span>Add new item</span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually am looking for how to give dynamic names to child elements like select and textbox

Comment: @KrishnakumarC please check i edited code for rename select box and you can set other input fields name as required. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generate some unique random numbers and append it to your id using `.attr()` method

```js
jQuery(function() {
     jQuery('#act').click(function() {
         var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
         var el = jQuery("#test").clone(true, true).insertAfter("div#test:last").attr('id', 'test' + randomnumber);
       console.log('id = ' + el.attr('id'));
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
    <label class="label" for=""</label>
    <div class="control">
        <select name="super_attribute" id="attribute" class="super-attribute-select">
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <button type="submit"
        title=""
        class="action primary tocart"
        id="act">
    <span>Add new item</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually am looking for how to give dynamic names to child elements like select and textbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change just the new elements, apply `map` (from the top of my head, untested);

```js
jQuery(".test").clone(true, true).map(function(el, index) {
    return jQuery(el).attr("id", "test-" + index);
}).insertAfter("div.test:last");
```

Also, selecting multiple elements by ID (`#test`), will probably not work, and it's not allowed according to the spec to have multiple elements on a single page with the same ID. So that's why I used a class selector in my code above.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".elem1")
  .clone()
  .insertAfter(".elem1")
  .addClass('elem2');
```

Then, loop foreach .elem2 element